# Custom args for each instance of Chrome when running parallel tests with Protractor

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, parallel-processing, protractor

Is it possible to pass custom args for each instance of Chrome when running parallel tests in Protractor? I need to know the Remote debugging port for each instance so I can connect with the Dev Tools protocol.

As I see it there's two options. Set the port to a specific unique value for each instance, or let it be set automatically and fetch it somehow when preparing the tests. Would it be possible with any of these options?

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    chromeDriver: chromeDriverPath,
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: process.env.HEADLESS && puppeteer ? ['--headless',  `--remote-debugging-port=${DEV_TOOLS_PORT}`] : [`--remote-debugging-port=${DEV_TOOLS_PORT}`],
            binary: puppeteer.executablePath()
        },
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the two options are solved. But I would still like to know if there's a possibility to use custom args for each instance.

```
// Get Remote debugging port for chrome
let chromeRemoteDebuggingPort;
browser.getCapabilities().then((capabilities) => {
    const chromeOptions = capabilities.get('goog:chromeOptions');
    if( chromeOptions && chromeOptions.debuggerAddress) {
        chromeRemoteDebuggingPort = chromeOptions.debuggerAddress.split(':')[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: so what is the question now?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: I would still like to know if there's a possibility to use custom args for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem right, what you could do is to pass parameters as env variables to protractor on start. So your config would look like this:

```
exports.config = {

    framework: 'jasmine',
    chromeDriver: chromeDriverPath,

    multiCapabilities: [{
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'chromeOptions': {
        args: [`--remote-debugging-port=${process.env.PORT_ONE}`]
      }
    }, {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
      'chromeOptions': {
        args: [`--remote-debugging-port=${process.env.PORT_TWO}`]
      }
  }]
}
```

And then start your protractor process with env variables like so:

`PORT_ONE=90 PORT_TWO=80 protractor protractor.conf.js`

Comment: Thanks, but that will unfortunately not work. We only start one protractor instance. Then protractor spawns multiple instances of Chrome.

Comment: exactly, if you do it this way, then you run the command once in CL and it starts 2 chrome instances

Comment: But till will run all tests twice, once for each browser, right? How would you split the tests between the browsers? I don't understand.